# Word for a small short cylindrical glass container (for salves, creams etc.)

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine you have a salve, perhaps a vapor rub or a hand cream. It comes in a small, circular (or to be more accurate, cylindrical) metal container.

Typically, I would say:

> I have a "tin" of that vapor rub if you want some.

However, I'm writing a fantasy story where they would never dream of wasting metal on such a frivolous pursuit - rather, they use glass because sand is everywhere.

I've looked in a thesaurus but all I'm finding are things like *container* and *dish*. Dish might make sense but I don't think of dish as having a closing lid. It's too short to be a jar.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108144/discussion-on-question-by-corsika-word-for-a-small-short-cylindrical-glass-conta).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I make salves, so I often buy containers online. Most websites call a short jar a "squat jar." It usually has a wide mouth in comparison to its height. Here's a [picture of one in an online shop](https://www.jarsdirect.com/product-page/50ml-amber-squat-glass-jar).

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but this sounds like a trade term to me. I would not expect to hear it in everyday life.

Comment: In everyday life, I'd simply call it a jar

Comment: Links are ephemeral; please post the image directly here.

Answer (score 44):

There is no height limit on a jar. I have several in my fridge that are less than an inch high and some are several inches wide.

It is perfectly fine to call a small container made of glass or ceramic a jar.

Comment: +1 for jar. Search amazon or another retailer for maple butter, and you'll find many in very short jars that include phrases in their descriptions such as "Be careful—you might be tempted to eat the whole jar with a spoon".

Comment: I feel sure that in Britain we would call them "pots". Though a bigger one containing jam, or pickled onions, we would call a "jar". What do yours contain?

Comment: "Pot" is also the word that I would use for the small container like salve or lip balm, and I am from the US.

Comment: When describing the object for the first time, you could call it a shallow jar, or something like that. To me that would get across the image you described.

Comment: Interesting, I would never call something smaller than a liter or so a "pot."

Comment: @WS2 I would consider a "pot" to be something you plant vegetation in, rather than container for makeup or processed food. If someone presented me with a wall full of shelves filled with ceramic jars and asked for a specific pot, I'd probably make the connection, but it's not a good one as it wouldn't be made in other situations, IMO. If you were to put me in front of the same wall, but it was half filled with gardening supplies, I'd probably hand you a plant.

Answer (score 13):

Another word for such a container is a [**tub**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tub#Noun).

Comment: AmE speaker here; this is the first word that came to mind.

Comment: This is quite interesting - I don't think anything made of glass in the UK would be termed a "tub". To me, a "tub" is a plastic container e.g. a tub of yoghourt. Made of glass it is a pot or a jar.

Comment: @WS2 Good point.  (As a UK native myself, I should have considered that!)  Though glass is mentioned in the question only as an example; it could equally be made of some type of plastic, or waxed cardboard, or rubber, or similar — and I think we'd both be happy with ‘tub’ for those.

Comment: "tub", to me, implies the width is greater than the height.

Comment: @WS2 - The OP asked about a metal container, not a glass one.

Comment: @MaxW If you read the question carefully to the end, you will see they are talking of a glass container.  A "tub" to me, originally of wood, is nowadays applied to some plastic containers. A metal container would almost definitely be "a tin".

Comment: The word "tub" is too generic for this specific purpose. A bathtub is sometimes ceramic, metal with a ceramic coating, or plastic/vinyl. I use butter from a plastic tub, and I have Rubbermaid brand tubs, that are often called totes, which are a a rubberized plastic. And nothing in the definition of "tub" even remotely implies glass, but rather the definition uses examples that are anything but glass. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tub

Comment: @computercarguy Yes, but we don't use the term "bathtub". The thing you sit in is a "bath". A "tub" suggests a wooden thing like a water butt, or else something of a modern material which cannot be a glass, a jar or a pot.

Comment: @WS2, I had to look up "water butt", which brought up some, um, "interesting" options. And "bathtub" is used extensively in the US, whereas a "bath" is something you take in a bathtub. The OP doesn't say location, so it's difficult to figure out what dialect or jargon they are interested in, unless they have it posted in their profile on on another question. And their profile says Canada, so likely neither AmE or BrE, or maybe a mix.

Comment: @computercarguy So what do you call water-butts? They used to be called water-tubs when I first knew them about 70 years ago - when they were made of wood - a bit like barrels.

Comment: @WS2, well, the few people who still use them call them rain barrels, since they are usually 50 gallon steel barrels. Larger ones are sometimes pits or tanks. Unfortunately, the practice isn't very common in the USA anymore. We had a cistern on the farm +30 years ago, but I don't remember what we used that water for.

Comment: AmE: Tub, as a food or cosmetic container, has a strong connotation of being plastic and disposable. The only products I can think of that come in a "tub" are butter and margarine.

Answer (score 9):

The first thing that comes to my mind is a [**vial**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vial).

Comment: Vial is a narrow-necked container and mainly used for liquids. It is not good for salves, creams.

Answer (score 4):

The possibly-appropriate word *[vial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vial)* has already been suggested, but I think *[phial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phial)*, "glass vessel or bottle, especially a small bottle for medicines", is a better choice for fantasy fiction.  Also consider *[ampoule](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ampoule)*, *[flask](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flask)*, and *[cuvette](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cuvette)*, "a small vessel with at least two flat and transparent sides".

Also note a number of related words that appear in a passage in Chapter 9 of *The Nursing Home Murders* by Ngaio Marsh:

> "...Now I understand that the jar, bottle, or pot containing the
> serum—"
>
> "It was an ampoule," said Jane.
>
> "So it was—and the pipkin, cruse, or pottle containing hyoscine were
> on the table. ..."

From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jar#Etymology_1), ***jar*** in sense 2 means "A small, approximately cylindrical container, normally made of clay or glass, for holding fruit, preserves, etc., or for ornamental purposes.  ... Synonyms: cruse, pot".

From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bottle#Etymology_1), ***bottle*** means "A container, typically made of glass or plastic and having a tapered neck, used primarily for holding liquids".  [Many bottles have straight rather than tapered sides.  Certain metal containers are referred to as water bottles, fuel bottles, etc.]

From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pipkin), ***pipkin*** means "A small earthen pot".

From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cruse#Etymology), ***cruse*** means "A small jar used to hold liquid, such as oil or water".

Per [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pottle), ***pottle*** means "A small pot or other receptacle, e.g. for strawberries".

Comment: Same word, slightly different route into present-day spelling :)

Answer (score 0):

A tin doesn't necessarily have to have a lid, so I would call a container as you describe it "**a glass**".

Comment: For me (British English) a "glass" is an open-topped vessel to hold a drink, not a container for a cream. Agree with other answers suggesting "pot" or "jar". Less keen on the word "tub" because that often suggests a large container.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Also true Canadian English, and I think it's true of US English as well.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I was thinking that in a fantasy setting where glass was used like metal is used in the real world, the word "glass" might easily come to encompass both meanings. Also, if one were to take a glass and put cream inside it, it would still be a glass.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Yes, true of US English, at least in my experience.

Comment: The phrase "glass jar" would be fine, but not "glass" on its own.

Comment: @AdrianHHH "jar" had already been given as an answer :-) I'll stand by my choice of "glass" as I feel it makes sense in the context of the question. If "fantasy story" hadn't been specified in the question then I wouldn't have posited this as an answer.

Comment: As I use a Ball jelly jar as a glass from time to time, and a 4 oz widemouth Ball jar might be just perfect for the Ops ointment, it's fair.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

A **dram** might work - generally refers to a specific quantity, but it has its origins in pharmaceutical products, and was a common size small jar for selling medicine or other similar products.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **The Free Dictionary's** thesaurus [here](https://www.freethesaurus.com/jar).

If you scroll down you will find a listing provided by wordnet that looks like this:

[image: WordNet listings]

Answer (score 0):

Where I come from, it's a *bottle* if it's narrow and a *jar* if it's wide.

For your purposes, I also like the above suggestion *vial*.

A *glass* is something you drink out of, a *pot* is big and usually for cooking, and a *tub* is even bigger and usually for washing. They're great words, but I don't think they're what you want.